# using apex to identify fields in a query that spans multiple objects

Tags: apex, soql

I have a query like the following (sample) where the query is pulling fields from multiple objects.

```
list<contact> cons = [select id, lastName, account.name, account.custom_field__c from contact];
```

How can I dynamically identify the fields in cons using apex?

Thanks

Comment: My goal is to create a method that takes a generic query result and returns a csv file.  To do so, I need the ability to interrogate the field names.

Comment: I don't think what you want can be done... There is no way to get a `List<SObjectField>` based on a given `List<SObject>`. You could go the other direction, but that doesn't seem to be what you are asking.

Comment: exactly!  making it generic is the fun part.

Comment: when you say "the other direction" what do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39927/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-sberley).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of "Summer 16", you can [Get a Map of Populated SObject Fields](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_apex_sobject_getmap.htm):

> **Get a Map of Populated SObject Fields**
>
> Previously, iterating over just the populated the fields of an SObject
>   involved some complicated programming. For example, if you queried an
>   SObject using SOQL, it wasn’t easy to tell which fields were returned.
>   In Summer ’16, we’ve introduced a new method on the SObject class that
>   returns a map of populated field names and their corresponding values:
>
> `Map<String, Object> getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()`
>
> contains only the fields that have been populated in memory for the
>   SObject instance, which makes it easy to iterate over those fields. A
>   field is populated in memory in the following cases.
>
> - **The field has been queried by a SOQL statement.**
> - The field has been explicitly set before the call to the getPopulatedFieldsAsMap() method.
>
> Fields on related objects that are queried or set are also returned in the map.

Reference: **[Summer '16 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_apex_sobject_getmap.htm)**